# Measuring quantum entanglement in paper by Ma et al

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Looking at the links below, could somebody please explain how entanglement between Alice and Bob particles is established/deduced from Victor's choice/measurement? I understand that Alice and Bob can make measurements in any one of three bases (Left/Right, Vertical/Horizontal, Up/Down). What I don't get is how Victor's choice of entangled-state measurement or a separable-state measurement affects the interpretation of what Alice and Bob see. Could you walk me through it?

p.s. *I don't have a physics degree and have done as much research as I can on my own. Please don't patronize. Kindly answer in non-technical terms if you can. Dumb it down for me. Thanks.*

http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v8/n6/fig_tab/nphys2294_F1.html

http://scienceblogs.com/principles/wp-content/blogs.dir/467/files/2012/05/i-73566aff3cb6482126dbe73ad83b73fd-entanglement_swap_data.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delayed choice entanglement swapping: why are Alice & Bob's measurements useless without Victor's?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190215/)